# installing py-torch in anaconda , got error

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, failed-installation

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/02/880b468bd382dc79896eaecbeb8ce95e9c4b99a24902874a2cef0b562cea/torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch) (5.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: torch
  Building wheel for torch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_w68wcvp' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
      description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch
  Complete output (2 lines):
  running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
Failed to build torch
Installing collected packages: torch
    Running setup.py install for torch ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x966ekmg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67llvrv3\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\vinayak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67llvrv3\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x966ekmg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the right options based on hardware configuration and install it from 
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Should work without any problems.